# Qué hace _Thread_local en lenguaje C

Tags: c, punteros

Podrían explicarme que hace el siguiente programa y cómo imprimo algún resultado para saber que obtengo. Estoy aprendiendo lenguaje C y me topé con este problema.

```
int main( void )
{
char a[100];
int* b = ( int* )&a;
*b = 1;

static char c[100];
b = ( int* )&c;
*b = 2;

_Thread_local char d[100];
b = ( int* )&d;
*b = 3;
}
```

Por supuesto que lo quiero compilar y me da error en esa línea de código.

Comment: Qué error te da?

Comment: google.com-> _Thread_local -> primer resultado -> traducir... listo.